# Comparing two strings in Java

Tags: java, android, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I know it' a dumb question but why this code doesn't work.

```
boolean correct = "SampleText"  == ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
    if(correct) ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("correct!");
    else ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("uncorrect!");
```

The point is to check if content of "editText1" is equal to "Sample Text"

Comment: you are actually do a identity check with two `String` instances.

Comment: use == for primitive data types only, use equals() method for objects and strings

Comment: Look into [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: This kind of questions are the result of no research...

Comment: what kind of component is EditText?

Comment: @RicardoE http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: So what is the output of: System.out.println(R.id.editText1); ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java, two strings (and in general, two objects) must be compared using `equals()`, not `==`. The `==` operator tests for *identity* (meaning: testing if two objects are exactly the same in memory), whereas the method `equals()` tests two objects for *equality* (meaning: testing if two objects have the same *value*), no matter if they're two different objects. Almost always you're interested in equality, not in identity.

To fix your code, do this:

```
String str = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
boolean correct = "SampleText".equals(str);
```

Also notice that it's a good practice to put the string literal first in the call to `equals()`, in this way you're safe in case the second string is `null`, avoiding a possible `NullPointerException`.

Comment: *"Also notice that it's a good practice to put the string literal first in the call to `equals()`, in this way you're safe in case the second string is null, avoiding a possible `NullPointerException`."* In robust code, that's actually an argument **against** putting the literal first. You **want** the NPE if your logic fails to handle that situation prior to the comparison, most of the time, so you can fix the logic before release.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's open to discussion. Some static-analysis checkers will generate a warning if you _don't_ compare strings as I suggested above. One could argue that comparing strings in this way handles a corner case better than explicitly testing at all places to see if a string is null

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for example, look at the `EqualsAvoidNull` check in [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html)

Comment: @ Óscar: As you say, it's something people can disagree on. I **never** check with the literal first, because it reads poorly (to native English speakers and indeed native speakers of most other western languages) and because, again, I want the NPE if I've done something stupid. So far? Precisely *zero* production bugs related to it. Some nice bugs caught in testing, which I then was able to fix. But again, it's something reasonable people can, and do, disagree on. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Java `Strings` have to be compared with their `equals()` method:

```
String foo = "foo";
String bar = "bar";
if (foo.equals(bar)) System.out.println("correct");
else System.out.println("incorrect");
```

Answer (score 1):

to compare the values for two strings (for equality), you need to use equals, not ==  (or use equalsIgnoreCase if you do not care about case sensitivity).
Using equals will check the contents/values of the strings (as opposed to "==" which will only check if the two variables point to the same object - not the same value).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to compare 2 objects in java is using `equals() method of Object class`
And as String is an object in java, it should be compared in same way.

The correct way to compare a String is with,

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

So you can use this,

`boolean correct = "SampleText"`**.equals**`(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("SampleTest".equals(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString()) ? "correct!" : "incorrect!");
```

It's a bit long and theres probably a better way you could do this. The .toString() feels weird!